# How to load legacy OS in mbr disk with uefi code

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, mbr

I am programing with EDK2, I want to load a legacy OS with my UEFI app in UEFI mode.

The firmware supports UEFI/Legacy. The legacy os win7 will start, if I do nothing. The efi shell will start if I choose to boot from my fat32 usb block device with an efi shell.

I've read the source code in UDK2014\IntelFrameworkModulePkg\Library\GenericBdsLib (UDK2014 is my workspace for edk2), the function LegacyBoot in EFI_LEGACY_BIOS_PROTOCOL didn't work out, I failed again even if link to GenericBdsLib, I don't know which detail I ingored. ask for help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I success to boot a legacy OS or UEFI OS with UEFI Code, The legacy OS means the OS in MBR Disk, the UEFI OS means a efi app (it's a simple way to load a image, we can ingore it).

What cause I failed to boot a legacy os is the missing option. I create an option with BdsCreateOneLegacyBootOption and update L"BootOrder", then LegacyBoot in EFI_LEGACY_BIOS_PROTOCOL work out if I choose the bootoption created by BdsCreateOneLegacyBootOption. The LegacyBoot needs a Devictpath, I extracted the DevicePath from the bootoption which was created by BdsCreateOneLegacyBootOption, and the optiondata from the bootoption which was created by BdsCreateOneLegacyBootOption. I failed if I choose the bootoption in bootmenu, cause the deferent devicepath and optiondata. The bootoption changed after reboot, maybe the mainboard did something I don't know.

PS:The function BdsCreateOneLegacyBootOption need a BBSTable, and export a bootorder list, we should update the bootorder list in the variable L"BootOrder". BBSTables can be built by GetBbsInfo in EFI_LEGACY_BIOS_PROTOCOL.

Answer (score 2):

First: **why bother?** This may sound like a snide and dismissive comment, but it's a serious query. There *are* legitimate reasons to boot a BIOS-mode OS on an EFI-based computer, but your question presents no motivation for doing so. From a programming perspective, this task is a pain; and as you say the target OS is Windows 7, which supports EFI-mode booting, it's not even remotely clear to me that it's worth the effort. Also, there are three existing ways to do this, with no new code being written....

The first way of doing it is to use your computer's built-in boot manager. It should present options to boot either whatever EFI-mode OS you've installed or in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. Details of how to access this menu vary from one computer to another, though, and the details of what will appear on the menu will vary. Most commonly, BIOS-mode boots from disks are identified by the disk's manufacturer or model number, whereas EFI-mode entries are given names associated with the OS, like `Windows boot manager`. The result of using this method won't be exactly what you describe (namely, launching Windows from your own EFI application), but it may be adequate to your needs.

The second method is to use my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) Like the computer's built-in boot manager, rEFInd lets you launch either BIOS-mode or EFI-mode boot loaders (providing the firmware supports both). One caveat is that, on UEFI-based PCs, this feature is disabled by default; you must edit `refind.conf` to uncomment the `scanfor` line and ensure that `hdbios` is among the options. (If the target BIOS-mode OS is on an external disk or CD, there are other keywords for those -- see the comments in the `refind.conf` file for details.) Like the built-in boot manager, this solution won't *exactly* do what you say you want, but it may be adequate. Also, you could have your application launch rEFInd, which you could configure with a short timeout to launch the BIOS-mode OS by default. This approach would have exactly the effect you desire, although rEFInd carries significant overhead, so it would be a rather inelegant solution.

rEFInd is also relevant to your question because it includes code to do what you want. You should focus on the `refind/legacy.c` and `EfiLib/legacy.c` source code files. Be aware, though, that rEFInd includes *two entirely distinct* BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode boot paths, one for Macs and one for UEFI-based PCs. Since you refer specifically to UEFI, chances are you want the latter, not the former. In the `refind/legacy.c` file, the UEFI code resides mostly in functions whose names include the string `UEFI`; the other functions are for the Mac. The `EfiLib/legacy.c` file contains UEFI-path code exclusively; but most of these functions are taken from TianoCore EDK2, so you might not need to duplicate them. (Since rEFInd is designed to be built with either EDK2 or GNU-EFI, I've ended up extracting a lot of EDK2 code so it can be built with GNU-EFI.) OTOH, these functions may have been modified from their EDK2 origins, so you might need to do more tweaking to get things working correctly if you use the EDK2 originals. Note that rEFInd uses the GPLv3, so if you intend to distribute your program, using rEFInd code will necessitate using the GPLv3 or a compatible license.

The third way to do the job is to use the [Clover boot manager.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cloverefiboot/) This is a Hackintosh boot manager that, like rEFInd, is partially derived from the older (and now abandoned) [rEFIt boot manager.](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) Like rEFInd, Clover includes code to launch BIOS-mode OSes; however, it does so in a different way from what rEFInd does. You could use Clover much like you'd use rEFInd, either as a piece of your boot path or as sample code to extract and incorporate in your own program. Although Clover's Sourceforge page says it uses the BSD license, that's not entirely true; some of the source code files specify that it uses the GPL.

Unfortunately, as you'll soon learn if you start perusing rEFInd's or Clover's code, the task of launching a BIOS-mode boot loader from EFI is non-trivial; I can't just throw up a few lines of code for you to use. Also, be aware that I did not write this code myself; rEFInd's code was contributed to the project by somebody else, and although I've perused Clover's code, I can't claim to understand it. I have modified rEFInd's BIOS-mode boot code a bit, but I may not be able to provide a lot of help to you in adapting it to your own program.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. I've already read the source code in Clover boot manager.It's useful.and I finally success to load the legacy os or UEFI os after the user do choose

Answer (score -1):

> The legacy os win7 will start, if I do nothing.

Great.  So, is there a problem?

I guess I'll focus on the question's title: How to load a legacy OS in MBR disk with UEFI code....

Pphf.  Forget it.

(U)EFI is essentially the basic software that starts when your computer powers on.  So, if (U)EFI does the same thing, then why don't we just call it "Basic Input/Output System", just like the prior software that was used for booting such old operating systems?

The reason we gave (U)EFI a new name is because it isn't compatible.  It was a new system designed from scratch.

Or, well, actually, it wasn't compatible.  I've been noticing lately that there are some new settings related to "Legacy" support.  So maybe newer versions have been adding some support for compatibility with the old ways of doing things.  But you can't expect to run the older software if you're choosing to disable the features that provide compatibility with the legacy support.

The most famous job of the BIOS is to do things like perform a POST and provide the operating system with some basic ways to interact with the hardware when the operating system starts.  However, at least some operating systems would continue to interact with the BIOS well after the operating system has been running for a long time.  For instance, when the computer tries to access a drive to access data, the operating system might use its own code, or the operating system might just pass on some requests to some programming code that is part of the BIOS.  (The details could depend on what operating system you use, and details like what drivers you use.)

If you're going to use an operating system that is designed to rely on the BIOS, you need to supply the BIOS-compatible programming code, using an actual BIOS startup chip, or maybe some sort of (U)EFI legacy feature.  You can't just use (U)EFI without that legacy support; that is why (U)EFI was given a new name.

Basically, (U)EFI was (initially) designed to support GPT, rather than rely on MBR.

Comment: There are some mainboard can load UEFI OS or Legacy OS, It depends on which option you choose in the boot menu. eg. the legacy or UEFI will show in boot menu if you installed a legacy os and insert a shell usb,then you can choose the boot option.
What I want to do is loading a device which the user will choose.an finally I success to do that.

Comment: @TOOGAM I am your downvoter. You did not answer the topicstarter question, you have created own thread instead.

Comment: @TOOGAM E.g. I may find the question, because I have to do fast test of other OS (like OpenBSD) with EDK2 in legacy mode on already partitioned hdd.

Comment: @user1742529 Having reviewed my answer again, including the paragraph starting with the word "If", I believe I address the root goal (of booting with UEFI) by saying it is incompatible unless "using"... "some sort of (U)EFI legacy feature" which adds compatibility.  (Although, see also next comment...)

Comment: Regardless, I'm so dissatisfied with the clarity of this question (which starts off talking about "programing" and later talks about "the function", so it sounds more like a programming question, but much of the rest sounds more like an effort to just get a basic boot).  What the actual question is seems like basically a "guess your own interpretation".  I don't mean to dismiss non-native difficulty in asking, but based on the ambiguity of this "question" (with zero question marks, mind you), I wouldn't penalize anyone for answering a different question than the one I had in mind.

Comment: Having said all that, maybe that sounds like a justification and a hope for the downvote to be reversed.  That is not so.  I'm not asking for a reversal of the downvote.  I accept that consequence of how the voting system is set up, and appreciate the feedback.  Thank you for letting me know your thoughts.  That is way more than what many downvoters do.